# update data where conditions are okay and the rest

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `timeslots` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `timeslot` datetime NOT NULL,
  `service` int(1) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `timeslots` (`ID`, `timeslot`, `service`) VALUES
(1, '2021-07-02 14:00:00', NULL),
(2, '2021-07-02 15:00:00', NULL),
(3, '2021-07-02 16:00:00', NULL),
(4, '2021-07-02 17:00:00', NULL),
(5, '2021-07-02 18:00:00', NULL),
(7, '2021-07-03 15:00:00', NULL),
(8, '2021-07-03 16:00:00', NULL),
(9, '2021-07-03 17:00:00', NULL),
(10, '2021-07-03 18:00:00', NULL),
(11, '2021-07-04 14:00:00', NULL),
(12, '2021-07-04 15:00:00', NULL),
(13, '2021-07-04 16:00:00', NULL),
(14, '2021-07-04 17:00:00', NULL),
(15, '2021-07-04 18:00:00', NULL),
(16, '2021-07-05 14:00:00', NULL),
(17, '2021-07-05 15:00:00', NULL),
(18, '2021-07-05 16:00:00', NULL),
(19, '2021-07-05 17:00:00', NULL),
(20, '2021-07-05 18:00:00', NULL),



CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `ID` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `service` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `events` (`ID`, `service`, `start`, `end`) VALUES
(8044, 1, '2021-08-30 00:00:00', '2021-09-11 00:00:00'),
(8045, 2, '2021-08-12 16:05:00', '2021-08-12 18:00:00');
```

Now I would like to update the table timeslots and set the service values like the values of the table events:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `events`'; 
    $result = $db->query( $sql ); 
    
    if ($result) {
        
        while ($zeile = $result->fetch_object()) {
            
            $start = date_format(date_create($zeile->start),"Y-m-d H:0:s");
            $end = date_format(date_create($zeile->end),"Y-m-d H:0:s");
    
            $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE `timeslots` SET `service` = ?  WHERE `timeslot`  >= ? AND `timeslot` < ?");
            $sql->bind_param("iss", $zeile->service, $start, $end);
            $sql->execute();
        
            if (!$sql->execute()) {
                sendDebugMail(__FILE__,  "[".__LINE__."] : ".$db->error);
            }
    
        }
        
    }
```

This works.
But now I would like to set all other rows of the table timeslot, where the WHERE condition of the update command are not true, to service = NULL

How can I realize it?

Comment: One of the solutions : (1) add one more column say "processed" and set its value to be 0. (2) then in your update statement set this value to be 1 for the records affected. (3) now set all records with processed = 0 to service=NULL

Comment: All the other rows have already service = null, don't they?

Answer (score 0):

The above appears to be equivalent to...

```
UPDATE timeslots t
JOIN events e
ON t.timeslot >= e.start
AND t.timeslot < e.end   
SET t.service = ?
```

... which is considerably less typing, and orders of magnitude faster!